# How to set up proxy for pandas read_html?

Tags: python, html, pandas, http-proxy

I have a python script that utilizes pd.read_html to DataFrame data contain on a webpage. The script also loops different dates into the url so that I can read multiple days of data. I know the syntax of my script is correct but when I run it at a corporation with a proxy, it fails. This is the specific URL and the line that fails w/ the proxy:

```
url = r'https://services.tcpl.ca/cor/public/gdsr/GdsrNGTLImperial20191216.htm'

df = pd.read_html(url)
```

I believe that I need to provide proxy information to the the script.

I have used the following to pass through the proxy for other scripts but it does not work for my pandas scrape:

```
import os

proxy = "http://proxy-xxxx-xxx:85"

os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy
```

I also also used this for requests scripts but it does not work for pandas I do not think pandas.read_html() has an argument where you can pass through proxies like requests:

```
http_proxy = 'http://proxy-xxxx-xxx:85'
https_proxy = 'https://proxy-xxxx-xxx:85'

proxy_Dict = { 'http' : http_proxy,
               'https' : https_proxy,
             }

url = (r'http://www.tccustomerexpress.com/alberta/dashboard/ngtldash7days.csv')

r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxy_Dict).text
```

I am fairly new to how proxies and pandas work so I appreciate any information. I don't know if pandas uses requests or urllib3 in the background but if there is someway to "handshake" the website first with the proxy and then use pandas.read_html() that would be amazing.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You must use

```
request.get
```

Complete your code with:
`df = pd.read_html(StringIO(r))`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before today. Now I have saved it.
You can get the html by using 'request' and then read it by using 'pandas.read_html'
I don't know how to type in code type here.
Here is the methods:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
session = requests.Session()
session.proxies = {"http": "IP address: the "Proxy Port", "https": "IP address: the "Proxy Port", }
URL = 'www.example.com'
headers_default = 'your user-agent'
resp = session.get(URL , headers=headers_default,verify=False)
df  = pd.read_html(resp.text)
```

the 'df' is the table you need
I hope this answer can help you.